# Consuming MQ Messages: JMS Listener vs Message Driven Bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jms, ejb-3.1, message-driven-bean

Our IBM MQ Series queue **Q1** will be receiving XML messages that we need to consume, invoke XSLT and place the resulting XML on another queue **Q2**. The size of the messages is small (up to 5KB). We can have 50 different types of XML messages. They are independent of one another

The system is close to real-time, so we can have only small latency up to 1-2 mins. The worst case scenario is that all 50 files can come to the queue at the same time so the program needs to be relatively robust.

We use IBM Websphere App Server. Eclipse is used for development.

**Question:** Should we write a JMS program that implements *MessageListener* interface or a *Message Driven Bean* that would consume the message from queue **Q1**, call XSLT and place the resulting XML on **Q2**? What are the benefits, pros/cons of JMS vs MDB? I have not used JMS in years so would appreciate any thoughts, tips, and ideas on configuration, development and testing.

Answer (score 1):

The Message Driven Bean is an asynchronous message listener. I think it would be better making use of Message Driven Bean. That way you will get all the services provided by the ejb container like transactions, security, resources, concurrency, and message acknowledgment. Going the JMS program way you need to handle all these services specially the concurrency in your case yourself.